# migrate from weblogic to tomcat: directory mapping

Tags: java, tomcat, weblogic

I am trying to migrate from weblogic to tomcat. 
in weblogic I have

```
<virtual-directory-mapping>
  <local-path>E:/internal</local-path>
```

For example I have **mysite** project. It means that localhost:8080/mysite/ = E:/internal
and I can get a file from E:/internal through localhost:8080/mysite/

```
localhost:8080/mysite/file.jsp
```

I whole project is used:

> src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/file.jsp"

In [this article](http://harkiran-howtos.blogspot.ie/2009/08/map-external-directory-into-your.html) there is an examle how to map local folder to tomcat.

```
This
6. Now inside the above xml file put the following line: 
<context docbase="d:/images"></context>
```

doesnt work for me. I changed it to

```
(1) <Context  docBase="E:/internal"></Context>
```

It works. But I have a problem. For example I have localhost:8080/mysite/about page.

When I use (1) mapping

> src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/file.jsp"
>   doesnt work because it returns mysite/file.jsp

when I try to map **mysite** by creating mysite.xml the project is not starting because **mysite** is a site url.

**How can I resolve this problem?**

Comment: Any particular version of Tomcat?

Comment: Where are your files actually on the disk? Somewhere, you should have a WAR file or exploded-WAR directory. Are you trying to overlay `E:\Internal` on top of your WAR? If so, you'll need to take other steps. I'll outline those if I understand your original question properly.

Comment: Exploded-WAR directory is here "path to tamcat"\tomcat 7.0\webapps\mysite

Comment: [EDITED]:
Exploded-WAR directory is here: "path to tamcat"\tomcat 7.0\webapps\mysite
I want to store files (imagesm, docs etc) here: E:/internal.
["Are you trying to overlay E:\Internal on top of your WAR?"]: I am not sure I understand what you mean but the idea is to store the files in different plase that war file and to be able to access it using "mysite" alias. Note that mysite is a part of site url. like localhost:8080/mysite or www.mainproject.com/mysite

Comment: Okay, final question: do you want to "merge" the two directories (i.e. `CATALINA_BASE/webapps/mysite` and `E:\Internal`) or do you want to "mount" `E:/Internal` into some sub-URL-space like `/mysite/internal`?

Comment: I want to mount E:/Internal into /mysite
so localhost:8088/mysite/home will open home page but localhost:8080/mysite/logo.jpg will get the image from E:\Internal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best thing is probably to map each item in `E:\Internal` individually using the `aliases` attribute of your `<Context>` (see http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html). Note that using `/` as an "alias path" is not allowed, which is why you'd have to map each item in `E:\Internal` individually.

It would be better if you could use a particular URL space for `E:\Internal` like `/internal/[something]` and map the whole directory as an `alias`, but that might not be feasible for your project.

If you really want to "merge" the two directories (that is, resources from both `E:\Internal` *and* `CATALINA_BASE/webapps/mysite` are available via URLs like `/mysite/foo`, then you will have to use the VirtualDirContext like this:

```
<Context>
    <Resources className="org.apache.naming.resources.VirtualDirContext"
      extraResourcePaths="/=E:\Internal" />
</Context>
```

(See http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html#Virtual_webapp and http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/resources.html#VirtualDirContext_implementation).